# Is the modular multiplicative inverse $2^{-1}$ a special case in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for prime $p > 2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, inverse

I'm a non-mathematician but I've been reading up on number theory as part of furthering my understanding of cryptography, and I've been focusing particularly on modular arithmetic in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for $p > 2$, where $p$ is prime.

I'm mostly understanding it, but I came across the following example:

$$2^{-1}\textrm{ in }\mathbb{Z}_p\textrm{ is }\frac{p+1}{2}$$

This appears to work, and I can't find any counterexamples, but I'm struggling to understand whether it's a special case for $x=2$ or part of a more general rule, or where this identity was even derived from.

Further confusing me is that $x^{-1}=x^{p-2}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for $x \neq 0$, which would imply that $2^{p-2}\equiv\frac{p+1}{2}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for all prime $p > 2$, and I can't see how this arises.

How does this work?

Comment: If $p\equiv 1\bmod 3$ then $3^{-1} = - \frac{p-1}{3}$.

Comment: Note:  $2\times\dfrac{p+1}2=p+1\equiv1\pmod p$

Comment: Side note: $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is better notation: don't want to confuse with the $p$-adics $\mathbb{Z}_p$!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh, of course! Because $x \cdot x^{-1} \equiv 1$, and $p+1$ (mod $p$) $\equiv 1$ too. Perfect. If you can write that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @bounceback I'm referring to a particular book that consistently uses $Z_p$ and $Z_p^*$ as notation for groups and generators throughout, so it makes sense for me to use this particular notation, but I'll keep that in mind for the more general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all odd $n>2$ (in particular for all prime $n>2$),

$2\times\dfrac{n+1}2=n+1\equiv1\pmod n$,

so $2^{-1}\equiv\dfrac{n+1}2\pmod n$.

You are correct that, for prime $n>2$, $2^{n-2}\equiv2^{-1}$, so $2^{n-2}\equiv \dfrac{n+1}2\pmod n$.

This is essentially $2^{n-1}\equiv n+1\equiv 1\pmod n.$